# Modal component in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I've recently started to check out Angular 2 and TypeScript that comes with it, and I guess I'm kinda into it. However I'm not too sure about the whole "TypeScript way" of doing things, specifically the typing of variables and such.

I wrote this simple modal component which displays a modal when the `ModalApiService` has its `open` function called from anywhere in the application. There can be multiple modals on the same page that's why I had to also include the passing of a `modalId` to the modal so I could identify them correctly.

- Can this code be optimized in any way?
- Do I set the types in a correct way? Are there more things I should set a type for?
- Does TypeScript have any features that I'm not taking full advantage of here?

Component:

```
export class ModalComponent {
  public isOpen: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _modalApi: ModalApiService, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {

    let overlay = <HTMLScriptElement>document.getElementsByClassName('modal-overlay')[0];

    if (overlay) {

      overlay.addEventListener('click', (e: any) => {

        // Close the modal if a click is made on the modal overlay itself, not its children
        if ((e.target.getAttribute('class') || []).indexOf('modal-overlay') !== -1) {
          _modalApi.close(this.modalId);
        }
      });
    }

    _modalApi.isOpen$.subscribe(
      modal => {
        this.isOpen = modal.id === this.modalId ? modal.isOpen : false;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Component API service:

```
@Injectable()

export class ModalApiService {
  private _isOpen = new Subject<boolean>();

  isOpen$ = this._isOpen.asObservable();

  open(id: string) {
    this._isOpen.next({isOpen: true, id: id});
  }

  close(id: string) {
    this._isOpen.next({isOpen: false, id: id});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cool stuff, though instead of declaring _isOpen property as a `<boolean>` in the service class, you should provide a new interface (as you added `modalId`).
Something like:

```
interface IModalElementStatus {
    isOpen: boolean;
    id: string;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review and good first answer, enjoy your stay!

Comment: And how would I use it? Every time I try to use an Interface like this I fail miserably.

Comment: What do you mean by failing? In this case just replace a '<boolean>' with a interface name. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well since it's a `Subject` idk if your interface would work since `_isOpen` would be something completely different than just 2 properties. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, lots of optimisations can be done here. Have a look at

$uibModal's open function - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Particularly templateUrl. where you can pass in a url of a modal to use. Generally putting html onto a page which may never be used is bad practice

Comment: I'm using angular 2 not angular 1.

Answer (score 0):

Other suggestions:

- You should check the HostListener attribute from angular side
- Also I would recommend to check Renderer, I think it's not the best way how you try to access to element properties
- Why are you using `e: any`? this can be `Event`

I'm also not even sure how this code works, `this.modelId` is not defined.
Finally you should implement some methods, and for sure define the return value. 
E.g.:

```
close(id: string): Observable<IModalElementStatus> {
    this._isOpen.next({isOpen: false, id: id});
    return Observable.of.....
}
```

I know currently it's not returning anything!